# reference - Grothendieck on Thurston's work

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, teichmuller-theory, anabelian-geometry

In his 'dernières' years Grothendieck gets "interested" in Thurston's work.

*"[...] je me suis intéressé ces dernières années - **la géométrie hyperbolique à la Thurston** et ses relations au groupe de Teichmüller."* [1]

*" I finally allowed myself to become distracted by some reflection on the 'Lego-Teichmüller construction game', and pretty much so during last week. The occasion was a series of informal talks Yves Ladegaillerie has been giving in Molino's seminar, on Thurston's hyperbolic geometry game and his compactification of Teichmüller space. Yves was getting interested again in mathematics after a five year’s interruption. He must have heard about my seminar last year on “anabelian algebraic geometry” and the “Teichmüller tower”, and suggested I might drop in to get an idea about Thurston’s work. This work indeed appears as closely related in various respects to my
sporadic reflections of the last two years, just with a diametrically opposed emphasis – mine being on the algebro-geometric and arithmetic
aspects of “moduli” of algebraic curves, his on hyperbolic riemannian
geometry and the simply connected transcendental Teichmüller spaces
(rather than the algebraic modular varieties)[...]"* [2]

Activités de recherche ([Yves Ladegaillerie](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=31174)). Topologie algébrique et géométrie Variétés de dimensions 2 et 3.

> **Questions:** The interactions between Arithmetic (and/or Anabelian) geometry and low-dimensional topology have been studied afterward? It is known if there is a relation between Grothendieck's Teichmüller yoga ('Lego-teichmüller construction game') and Thurston's geometrization? Have been discovered intersections between Grothendieck's and Thurston's work afterward?

Note: I have found a [Master Class: Around Thurston-Grothendieck-Teichmüller theories](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/article1389.html) held in IRMA on May 9 - 17, 2014. 'This suggests that it is an active field of research'.

[1]: Récoltes et Semailles, Grothendieck. pg 401 (Cercueil 2 - ou les découpes tronçonnées).

[2]: Pursuing stacks, Grothendieck. pg 187

Comment: Athanase Papadopoulos works in this area (who was also the organizer of the conference you have mentioned). In https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02229 he has described Grothendiek's work on existence & uniqueness of Teichmuller's work in terms of low dimensional topology (i.e. Thurston's type of description). You can also have a look at the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9809057.

Comment: As mentioned in Cusp's comment [Athanase Papadopoulos](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~papadop/) works in this area, in particular, he is editor of the Handbook of Teichmüller theory. The volume [II](http://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=96) and [VI](http://bookstore.ams.org/emsilmtp-27) of the Handbook contain sections on Grothendieck Teichmüller theory.

Comment: Also, the following articles look very relevant: Grothendieck’s Reconstruction Principle and 2-dimensional Topology and Geometry, Feng Luo ([pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9904019v1.pdf)). Actions of the absolute Galois group, Norbert A'campo, Lizhen Ji, and Athanase Papadopoulos ([pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03387.pdf))